# How to get information about shared posts from facebook page?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get information about shared posts from a facebook page.  I want the names, id and number of friends of persons who shared a post on facebook page. I tried using graph API as:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/sharedposts?access_token=token
```

But it does not return anything. I also have read_stream permission for my facebook app that I am using.  Still it is not working.  Can anybody help me to get this information ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug related to this issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/), but from my testing, I've seen that some Post IDs return information on sharedposts correctly while others don't.

E.g., making a call to `188878314634195/sharedposts` returns information about who shared the post, but making the same API call on a different object ID `567974923315567/sharedposts` with shares doesn't work.

I believe this has something to do with the privacy settings of the users' who shared the post. In the latter example, two people have shared the post, but the API returns no data, meaning those two users could have strong privacy settings.